# Polynomial Long Division: an algebraic explanation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, algorithms

Polynomial long division is described on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) with an algorithm.  I would like to understand the algebra supporting this algorithm.  Can anyone provide this information?

Brief description of algorithm:

1. Divides the first term by the highest term of the divisor
2. Multiplies the divisor by the result
3. Subtracts the product in step 2 from the polynomial
4. Repeat starting at step 1 until "there is nothing to pull down".

The [Wiki long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) page describes an algorithm, but has no supporting algebra showing why it works.  [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) also indicates long polynomial division is the same algorithm used for common base 10 long division.

Comment: It is the same algorithm, and it works for the same reason: steps (1) through (3) leave you with a remainder whose degree is smaller than that of the original polynomial, just as in integer long division those steps result in a remainder smaller than the original number. This process must terminate after a finite number of steps, since it is impossible to have an infinite, strictly decreasing sequence of non-negative integers.

Comment: I used the polynomial algorithm and it produced a result in a different form from the standard long division algorithm which is taught in elementary school.  I.e. the result did not come out to $a_n x^n + ... + a_0 x^0$ where $a_n < x$.  For instance I tried $\frac {2* 10^1 + 8 *10^0} {7* 10^0} = \frac 2 7 10^1 + \frac 8 7 10^0 = 4$.  I don't recall rational results in the standard long division algorithm.   Also, for that algorithm there is  a shift of position to the right until the dividend can be divided.  Unsure how that is expressed above.

Comment: Integer long division is done in the ring of integers. Polynomial long division is done in the ring of polynomials over some field, typically $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Q$ at the elementary level. Thus, the coefficients in the former will be integers, and the coefficients in the latter will be from whatever field is involved. That has nothing to do with the mechanics of the algorithm itself. You might find [this discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division) helpful.

Comment: I tried your posted algorithm for integer division and am having difficulty.  I tried $\frac {18} 9$.  $a = r = 18, b = 9$.  Dividing the first term of $18$, $\frac {1 b^1} {9 b^0} = 0$ and then $r = 18$.  If you follow the algorithm this continues forever, making $q = 0$.  I must be missing something?

Comment: You also mention the algorithm must terminate, which I assume is referring to $\mathbb{N}$.  How would this be the case with $b_{10}$ repeating decimals?

Comment: Of course in that case it does not terminate. It is also irrelevant: the base ten long division in question is division in $\Bbb N$. When we use the same method to compute a finite part of a decimal expansion, we are actually multiplying dividend and divisor by a high enough power of $10$ to make them integers, doing an integer long division, and then dividing by the same power of $10$; we just don’t think of it that way.